# Magento product export import not working?

Tags: magento-1.9, database, importexport

So I exported all my products by using the magento exporter under

```
System -> Import-Export -> Dataflow Profile -> Export all products
```

and then on the other magento installation:

```
System -> Import-Export -> Dataflow Profile -> Import all products
```

But the products where not imported, even though the import claims to be successfull. There were a few errors though, like missing pictures or sku on some products.

Is the product exporter not working in general or was it my fault?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the process is not so straightforward. To transfer products from one Magento to another simply export/import is not enough. After export and before you import products to new Magento installation you have to:

- make sure that product categories of your Magento 1.9 source are the same as in your target Magento, if not you need to manually re-create the same category tree
- also if you have some custom attributes/attribute sets created in source Magento, you need to create attributes and assign them to sets with exactly the same names and values in target Magento
- before import you need to copy product images from old Magento to media/import folder of target Magento

Comment: I think it is best to just import the whole database.